# Scheduled Tasks application installed , It stoped working after one time

Tags: installation, 10.04, package-management

I have installed the Gnome Schedule ( Scheduled tasks ) to automate the backup of the   on Ubuntu Lucid computer. The Scheduled tasks run for one time. I added one task and then next time it stoped running. Now everytime i run the application, the icon appears for few seconds in task bar , and application stops.  I tried reinstalling and rebooting computer many times  but same thing happens .
Any solution to this problem? I googled this problem for a long time. I couldn't find the solution for this.

I have found some comments on forum about running the application from terminal , So here it is the output of the warning when ran from terminal,

```
gnome-schedule
/usr/share/gnome-schedule/mainWindow.py:158: DeprecationWarning: Use the new widget gtk.Tooltip
  tip = gtk.Tooltips ()
/usr/share/gnome-schedule/mainWindow.py:159: DeprecationWarning: Use the new widget gtk.Tooltip
  tip.enable ()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/gnome-schedule/gnome-schedule.py", line 74, in <module>
    mainWindow = mainWindow.main(debug_flag, False, pr, manual_poscorrect)
  File "/usr/share/gnome-schedule/mainWindow.py", line 257, in __init__
    self.schedule_reload ()
  File "/usr/share/gnome-schedule/mainWindow.py", line 308, in schedule_reload
    data = self.at.read ()
  File "/usr/share/gnome-schedule/at.py", line 514, in read
    array_or_false = self.parse (line)
  File "/usr/share/gnome-schedule/at.py", line 174, in parse
    if script[-1] == "\n":
IndexError: string index out of range
```

**Update:**

Found similar post somewhere online [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1500904).

I just don't get it , how that worked for that person in that post.

Answer (score 1):

I figure that out with trial and error and some reading on other posts. I deleted folder named similar to the application which is gnome-schedule from the home folder. That worked for me. Once the Sheduler started, i deleted all the back up folders and other errorneous tasks from the application list. The application works for now.

I don't know , what happened to the app that made it not work for some reason. I am trying read more about how to properly use the Scheduled Tasks app , so that this won't happen again.

Thanks all for reading or not. I hope my answer would help someone in similar problem in future.